# My Canvas disapears because of occlusion

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a world space canvas, where I put an image.
On top of that image, I put a material with a custom shadder I found there http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/878667/world-space-canvas-on-top-of-everything.html

That works great, except when I come close to a big object, my UI dissapears.
When I clean occlusion, that works well.
Problem is my UICanvas and my image are not tagged as "static". Also I tried to bake when my UI canvas was disabled and I still have the same problem.

The shadder used by my UI elements has "Cull Off".

How it should be (Occlusion not baked) : [image]

How it is (Occlusion baked) : [image]

Components of an UI Button : https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7Gv9.jpg

When I move my UICanvas next to me (y > 0), my canvas appears.

Do you know why I can have this problem ?

Comment: I can't find anything about unity performing frustum culling on UI objects, even those in Worldspace. You can try [this answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/36446/disable-frustum-culling.html) but it doesn't look to me like it'll help.

Comment: Could you provide an image to better describe your problem?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `Far Clipping Plane` of the `Cameras` ?

Comment: @Hristo The Far Clipping Plane is set to 1000, and my object is more or less 16 unit away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue, add a second camera with depth only and change the culling mask to the layer of your UI elements.